# How can I call this destructor?

Tags: c++, templates

I know in the below example it's questionable to keep unsigned char* instead of T*, but assuming I wanted to keep the unsigned char pointer, how do I call the destructor?

```
template <typename T>
struct MYCLASS
{
    MYCLASS() { buffer = new unsigned char[sizeof(T)]; new (buffer)T(); }
    unsigned char* buffer;

    ~MYCLASS() { buffer->~T(); delete buffer; }
};


int main(void)
{
    MYCLASS<int> b;
}
```

The error I get in compiling is:

> Error C2325   'int': unexpected type to the right of '->~': expected
> 'unsigned char'

If I keep a T* I can call this fine. Assuming I want alias it with the unsigned char* instead, how can I call the destructor?

Comment: Use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: `new (buffer)T()` should return a pointer which you can keep to refer to the created `T`. The easiest solution is to store that pointer as a member and use it to call the destructor. Presumably, you want to do something with `T`, at which point having the pointer would also be helpful.

Comment: Beware that your class doesn't respect the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and will cause problems if anyone tries to move or copy a `MYCLASS`.

Comment: *"it's questionable to keep unsigned char* instead of T*,"* -- If you were to follow this with "because", you would have a natural segue into a description of what your code does. *On a related note, please add a description of what your code does; don't rely on people interpreting your code, especially if it does not work properly.*